# How do I control gpio pins through an email?

Tags: gpio

I need to know how do I activate or deactivate gpio pins when sending an email to a specific email address? I already have an email setup, I just don't know how to do the rest of what I want.

Comment: VoyagerLinuxGamer, this question is really broad, and doesn't show that you've put any kind of effort into figuring out the solution yourself.  This site is specifically a Q&A site, not a forum.  If you need help with specific parts, please feel free to ask, but as it is, your question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the RPi.GPIO Python library.  Your question does not exactly specify what you're trying to do, but for a general GPIO tutorial, check out this page on Make magazine:

http://makezine.com/projects/tutorial-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins-and-python/

Hope this helps.